# Bug : Dojo Dialog + Flash in Firefox 3

Tags: flash, dojo, dialog, firefox-3

i have a flash component on a dijit.Dialog.In Firefox 3, i cant click on the flash button.When i right click on the flash i get the tooltip(settings) far away from where i clicked.It's working on all other browsers.

I had to update dojo from 1.1 to 1.3 for IE 8 issue.After updating i seem to get this problem.Before it worked fine in dojo 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I gave the class .dijitDialogUnderlay an overflow:auto.

Now works fine.